# Cakephp: Load models without model files

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have tables that are created on the fly and I'd like to access it
thru Model. Since those tables are dynamically created, I don't have
the model .php files for them. The tables are created conforming to
Cake's naming convention. I tried to use loadModel() to load them but
Cake still complains that the tables are missing.

Is there a solution for it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**As of this writing, using CakePHP 2.1.2**

In your controller add `App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');`. Then instantiate the model

```
    $RemoteHeader = new AppModel(array(
                'table' => 'SOP10100',
                'ds' => 'external',
                'name' => 'RemoteHeader',
                'alias' => 'InvoiceHeader',
                'primaryKey' => 'id',
                'hasMany' => array(
                    'InvoiceDetail' => array(
                        'foreignKey' => 'SOPNUMBE',
                        'counterCache' => false
                ))));
```

then fetch the data with any Model parameters you need:

```
    $data = $RemoteHeader->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array(
            'SOPNUMBE',
            'CUSTNAME',
            'DUEDATE',
            'DOCDATE',
            'DOCAMNT',
            'SUBTOTAL')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `/app/models/dynamic.php` with class

```
class Dynamic extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Dynamic'
    var $useTable = null;
}
```

in Your controller's action

```
$this->Dynamic->useTable = 'newly-created-table';
```

It's not tested, let me know if having issues

Comment: I tried it and I still get "missing table" page as soon as I call $userInstance = ClassRegistry::init('Dynamic'); I have to do that because I am in a component.